# Reverting an hash code "sum"

Tags: java, math, integer, integer-overflow

So, rather than calculating the hash code every time, I thought I could keep an integer updated with all the changes. Imagine a setter for a property that contributes to the hash code:

```
public void setFoo(Foo newFoo){
    this.hashCalculator.remove(this.foo.hashCode()); // remove old hash code
    this.hashCalculator.add(newFoo.hashCode()); // add new hash code
    this.foo = newFoo; // set new foo
}
```

(I hope I'm not doing something stupid) I thought it would be simple math, but I am failing at implementing it. I think it has something to do with overflowing integers but I'm not sure. Clearly I'm missing something. The remainder from the division should probably be added back to the value, right?

This is the code I have. At the end the result should be 1, but it's not what I get.

```
class HashCode
{
    public int value = 1;

    public void add(int val){
        // as suggested by effective java
        value = value * 37 + val;
    }

    public void remove(int val){
        value = (value - val) / 37;
    }
}

HashCode o = new HashCode();

for(int a = 0; a < 1000; a++){
    o.add(a);
}

for(int r = 0; r < 1000; r++){
    o.remove(r);
}

System.out.println(o.value); // should be 1
```

Comment: You are right, it has to do with integer overflow.

Comment: And with arithmetics. You would need to "remove" your properties in the inverse order. This is most probably a useless, or even counterproductive optimization. Objects for which the hashCode matters should be immutable anyway, so they shouldn't have setters. Storing their hashCode can be useful then, because it never changes.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First: there is no way to properly reverse an operation that results in an integer overflow. Basically the problem is that you cannot know if the integer overflow happened once, twice or even more often in the previous operation. Therefore you cannot get the original `value` present before the last hash calculation.

Second: the hash calculation depends on the order of applied hash values.

```
((1 * 37 + 0) * 37 + 1) * 37 + 2 = 50692
((1 * 37 + 2) * 37 + 1) * 37 + 0 = 53428
           ^         ^         ^ the hash values.
```

Since the hash value change of appending the last value depends on all previous hash values you cannot just change one intermediary hash value, there is no (well performing) way to remove the impact the `1` in my previous example had on all future computations.

This should have been obvious if you tested your loops with `1`, `2`, `3`, etc. instead of `1000` to begin with. Without integer overflow your loops would have only worked if you remove the hash values in the opposite order you added them. That is a restriction that does not make sense to apply in "real-life". What @JB Nizet wrote in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47109253/reverting-an-hash-code-sum/47109346#comment81168838_47109253) is correct in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you. I knew I was doing something stupid, LOL, obviously it was never going to work... I wonder if it's a good idea avoiding the multiplication and using only + and - instead. That would be reversible.

Comment: @Wes but that would break the basic concept of distributing the hash values generated by the calculation evenly. It is by design that two objects with sub-hashcodes of (1 and 2) and (2 and 1) have different hash code and end up in different buckets. Hash collisions should be avoided.

Comment: Indeed... but I'm not sure what's worse, slightly less evenly distributed hash codes, or calculating the hash code every time... I was undecided between this weird idea and memoization... this is not possible, so the answer is obvious now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, when calculating with integers, you do arithmetic modulo 2^32. So in case of overflow it works if instead of dividing by 37 you multiply with its modular inverse -1857283155. For example this gives result 1:

```
    int pInv = -1857283155;
    int v = 1;

    for (int a = 0; a < 1000; a++) {
        v = v * 37 + a;
    }

    for (int r = 999; r >= 0; r--) {
        v = (v - r) * pInv;
    }

    System.out.println(v);
```

The second problem is that the hash when you add a then b is different from the value when you add b then a. This is cannot be solved with this hash function.

Comment: Thank you. I can see the problem now... obviously it must be reverted in reversed order.